# What does the linker actually do when linking a pointer variable to an array in C++?

Tags: c++

I have searched a lot for the extern-array-pointer problem but still feeling confused.

In the following code:

```
// example 1
//1.cpp
int a[]={1,2,3};  //the array a

//main.cpp
extern int*a;  //the pointer a
```

In `main.cpp`, when I use `printf` to print `a`, it gives me `1` which is the first four bytes of the array `a` defined in `1.cpp`. And printing `&a` gives me `0x1234`(for example) which is the address of the first element of the array `a` defined in `1.cpp`.

**It acts like the pointer `a` was connected with the array `a` by the address `0x1234` forcibly. Thus,  the value of the pointer `a` is what located at `0x1234`, which is `1`, since `sizeof(int*) == sizeof(int)` in 32-bit.**

I have learned that the linker needs the unresolved symbol table and the export symbol table to link declaration to definition.

While compiling `1.cpp`, symbol `a` was added to the export symbole table and while compiling `main.cpp`, symbol `a` was added to the unresolved symbol table. They should be named differently since their type is not the same.

In fact the linker could check the types of variable, because:

```
//example 2
//1.cpp
int a[]={1,2,3}

//2.cpp
extern char *a;
```

throwing a linking error that `char *a` was unresolved, but they don't mixed forcibly, linker could catch the error.
In single unit:

```
//example 3
int a[] = {1,2,3};
int *ptr = a;
```

the compiler convert the `a` variable to a temporary `int *` implicitly, but can not do that while in different units.

So why extern a pointer to receive an array is not caught by the linker. What does the linker actually do?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't think you're allowed to do that, so it would depend on the linker.

Comment: Your examples contain a One Definition Rule (ODR) violation. They are ill-formed, not diagnostic required.

Comment: @chris I compile and link by VS2017 and g++8.1, they are the same result.

Comment: @Igor The example 2 could contain. There should be `extern char *a`, I am sorry.

Comment: @sakugawa, Many things that aren't allowed will still compile and even run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C/C++ part can be dealt with immediately: with many implementations, C doesn’t **mangle** any symbols, since they’re all supposed to be unique, and lacking overloading for variables C++ doesn’t mangle them either.  (Variable *templates* are mangled, as are static data members.)  This isn’t a requirement of the language: formally, you have to use `extern "C"` for variables, but the standard *allows* collisions with unannotated global variables, and this happens frequently in practice (and is now a point of **backward compatibility**).  The rest is identical for C and C++.

What typical linkers manage are the **addresses** of every variable, with no type information except that implicit in the mangled names.  The address of an array is that of its first element, so your “pointer” ends up being an alias for that element (with the wrong type).  (Since this is, as pointed out in the comments, ill-formed, other hilarity can ensue like stores through the pointer not being visible through the array (as accessed via some other pointer).)  A different linker implementation could be more helpful, but again backward compatibility forbids it.

Comment: Some C++ compilers (e.g. Visual Studio) do mangle variable names. This makes it possible for the linker to detect the error in second example in the question.

Comment: @anatolyg: True, and I softened the language a bit to account for that, but it’s obviously not the situation that inspired the question.

Comment: @DavisHerring I try the second example by g++8.1 and there is no linking error, meaning that symbols' type infomation do miss while linking. So is this one aspect of how linker are implemented differently by VS2017 and g++?

Comment: @sakugawa: It’s an aspect of the ABI—several compilers use what is known as the Itanium ABI, which has that behavior.